# Apply matrixform to limited rows and columns of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a big matrix, you can say `1000*1000` whose elements are functions of several parameters such as `a, b`. I wish to see just a few (not all) rows and columns of the matrix in the `MatrixForm` which is a builtin function of *Mathematica*. For instance, row from `92` to `101` and column corresponded with `50` to `65`. How can I reach this goal?
In addition, if I want to simplify the elements, should I simply firstly and after that make use of `MatrixForm` or should I do vise versa? Which one is faster to run?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a function that shows a portion of a matrix in [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm), with associated row and column indices:

```
iMatrixView[m_, r_List, c_List] := Module[{sub = m[[r, c]]},
    augmented = ArrayFlatten[{
        {Map[Invisible, sub, {2}], List /@ istyle /@ r},
        {{istyle /@ c}, ""}
    }];
    Overlay[{
        Row[{RawBoxes@"(", Grid[sub, Spacings->1],RawBoxes@")"}],
        Row[{Invisible[RawBoxes@"("],Grid[augmented, Spacings->1]}]
    }]
]

istyle[x_] := Style[x, Gray, FontSize->Inherited-3]
```

For example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomInteger[150, {10, 15}];
iMatrixView[mat, {2,4,5}, {1, 6, 12}]
```

[image]

It is possible to use this function in a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate) to interactively explore the matrix:

```
MatrixView[mat_?MatrixQ, rows_Integer?Positive, cols_Integer?Positive] := With[
    {dim=Dimensions[mat]},

    Manipulate[
        iMatrixView[
            mat,
            Reverse[dim[[1]]+1-Range[rows]-u[[2]]],
            Range[cols]+u[[1]]
        ],
        {{u, {0,dim[[1]]-rows}}, {0,0}, Reverse@dim-{cols,rows}, 1}
    ] /; rows<dim[[1]]&&cols<dim[[2]]
]
```

For example:

```
MatrixView[mat, 6, 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful and Professional. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

```
M = RandomInteger[10, {1000, 1000}]; 
M // MatrixForm;

SubM = M[[92 ;; 101 , 50 ;; 65]];
SubM // MatrixForm
```

In terms of simplifying, it depends on a few things. Assuming that you only want to simplify the entries that you're extracting I think it'd be quicker to extract first, then simplify. If you simplify first then extract I'd think its almost equivalent to extracting twice since you first need to tell the computer which cells you want to simplify, which takes some time, then simplify them, then extract them, when if you extract them first and then simplify the whole thing, there are only two operations required, which logically should be quicker. Hope that helps.

Comment: your answer helped me fundamentally. Thank you so much